# String readLine() em Java

Tags: java, java-8

Estou com dificuldade em instanciar o método readLine() corretamente em java para que leia o arquivo, execute o while loop e escreva os dados pretendidos. Se alguém conseguir me ajudar, agradeço imenso!

código main.java:

```
package com.nayana.exercicio1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.HashSet;



public class Main {

    FileReader FileReader;
    BufferedReader BufferedReader;
    DateFormat format;
    HashSet<String> customer;
    HashSet<String> country;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter;
    Date date;
    ParseException ParseException;
    IOException IOException;
    int lines;
    String columns[];
    String line;
    String string;
    String formattedDate;
    Date datex;
    String readLine() {
        return null;

    }


}
```

código Process.java:

```
package com.nayana.exercicio1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Process {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
        Main pr = new Main();

        pr.BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\nayan\\Downloads\\orders_04_20_07.txt"));



        new String();

        pr.lines = 0;

        pr.customer = new HashSet<String>();
        pr.country = new HashSet<String>();


        System.out.println("Estas são as datas formatadas: " );


        while(pr.readLine() != null) {

            pr.columns =  ((String) pr.line).split(";");
            pr.lines++; 

            //CONTAR QUANTOS COSTUMERID DIFERENTES EXISTEM

            pr.customer.add(pr.columns[4]);
            pr.customer.size();

            //MOSTER DIFERENTES PAÍSES

            pr.country.add(pr.columns[6]);

            //CONVERTER DATA

            pr.string = pr.columns[2];
            pr.format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            pr.date = (Date) pr.format.parse(pr.string);
            pr.format.format(pr.date);
            pr.formattedDate= "";



            try {

                pr.datex = (Date) pr.format.parse(pr.columns[2]);
                pr.formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM");
                pr.formattedDate = pr.formatter.format(pr.datex);
            } catch (ParseException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(pr.formattedDate);


        }
        System.out.println("\nO número total de linhas é: " + pr.lines);
        System.out.println("\nO número total de CustomerId é: " + pr.customer.size());
        System.out.println("\nDiferentes países existentes" + pr.country);
    }

}
```

Comment: O loop fica infinito?

Comment: Sim, o objetivo seria ler todas as linhas do documento txt. Tá errado? Tem como me ajudar?

Comment: Readline() ler o arquivo todo ou por linha?

Comment: Ler o arquivo todo

Comment: Use então um comparador e não um loop. Use `if (pr.readLine() != null) {//your code }`

Comment: Já tentei, porém acaba por não retornar nenhum valor. Apenas "Estas são as datas formatadas: 

O número total de linhas é: 0

O número total de CustomerId é: 0

Diferentes países existentes[]
"

Comment: Quando eu utilizo todo o código com a mesma class, sem instanciar, ele funciona corretamente. Não consigo entender onde está o meu erro :/

Comment: Existe algum método que retorna tamanho de algum texto? Se puder coloca nas `pr.linhas` o tamanho.

Comment: Console diz algo?

Comment: Voce utiliza os valores de cada linha acedendo a `pr.line` mas esse valor nunca é afetado. Parece me que o que quer fazer é `while (true){ pr.line = pr.BufferedReader.readline(); if (pr.line == null) break;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua classe `Main` você tem o código abaixo, que sempre retorna `null`

```
String readLine() {
        return null;

    }
```

Dessa forma o loop nunca vai ser acessado `while(pr.readLine() != null)` sempre vai ser `null`.

Para funcionar, no lugar de usar esse `readLine null`, use o método do `BufferedReader`.

Outra coisa, o seu `pr.line` nunca é inicializado, ele precisa receber a linha, modificando o seu loop para o exemplo abaixo vai resolver.

```
while((pr.line = pr.BufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
```